# How to get values from arrays in one single line(Python 3)

Tags: python, list

I want to get all the values from the array `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` in one line and save it into another variable in **Python 3**

```
#This is the code I made and am getting the output "abcdefg" but am not sure 
#how to store the output ,instead of printing it out.
array_value = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
for x in array_value:
   print(x, end = '')
```

It might be a easy problem but I'm new to python and coding in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.
>   If there is any Unicode object in iterable, return a Unicode instead.
>   A `TypeError` will be raised if there are any non-string or non Unicode
>   object values in iterable. The separator between elements is the
>   string providing this method.

The following should do the trick:

```
array_value = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
output_string = ''.join(array_value)
print(output_string)

>>> "abcdefg"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I really get your problem. The solution depends on your types in array. For example with letters or strings it should be something like this:

```
array_value = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
output = "";

for item in array_value:
    output += item
    output += ' '

print(output)
```

If you have in array integers, floats or something else, try parse value with `str(variable)`.
But maybe helps context of your problem, like what type of output variable you would like to have. I am just guessing what you are looking for.

Hope it helps.